# NegaMax doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, chess, minmax

I have a problem with implementing a simple NegaMax in my chess programm.

According to several websites negamax should look as follows in my code:

```
int Position::negaMax(int curr_depth, int depth) {
    cd = curr_depth-1;
    if (curr_depth==depth) return evaluate();

    int max = -500000;

    calc_moves(true);
    doBackup(cd);
    for (int i=0;i<mvSize[cd];i++) {
        move_figure(mvD[cd][i][0],mvD[cd][i][1],mvD[cd][i][2],mvI[cd][i][0],mvI[cd][i][1]);    
        int score = -negaMax(curr_depth+1,depth);
        cd--; undoMove(cd);

        if (curr_depth==1)
            cout << "Move: " << getMoveString(i) << ", Score: " << score << endl;        

        if (score>max)
            max=score;
   }
   return max;
}
```

But with this code I get this output:

```
Move: a2a3, Score: 0
Move: a2a4, Score: 0
Move: b2b3, Score: 0
Move: b2b4, Score: 0
Move: c2c3, Score: 0
Move: c2c4, Score: 0
Move: d2d3, Score: 0
Move: d2d4, Score: 0
Move: e2e3, Score: 0
Move: e2e4, Score: 0
Move: f2f3, Score: 0
Move: f2f4, Score: 0
Move: g2g3, Score: 0
Move: g2g4, Score: 0
Move: h2h3, Score: 0
Move: h2h4, Score: 0
Move: b1a3, Score: 0
Move: b1c3, Score: 0
Move: g1h3, Score: 0
Move: g1f3, Score: 0
score: 0
```

That can't be right, if I negaMax for ply3 from the starting position.

If I remove the minus sign in front of the recursive function call, I get a more better result. But in my opinion that can't be right, because without the minus sign in the above code, I only maximize the score for one player, but not for the both.

```
Move: a2a3, Score: 0
Move: a2a4, Score: 30
Move: b2b3, Score: 0
Move: b2b4, Score: 30
Move: c2c3, Score: 0
Move: c2c4, Score: 30
Move: d2d3, Score: 295
Move: d2d4, Score: 295
Move: e2e3, Score: 295
Move: e2e4, Score: 295
Move: f2f3, Score: 0
Move: f2f4, Score: 30
Move: g2g3, Score: 0
Move: g2g4, Score: 30
Move: h2h3, Score: 0
Move: h2h4, Score: 30
Move: b1a3, Score: 30
Move: b1c3, Score: 30
Move: g1h3, Score: 30
Move: g1f3, Score: 30
score: 295
```

I've tried to implement different versions of MinMax, NegaMax and AlphaBeta. But I always get a score of 0. I would be very thankful for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual skeleton of negamax appears to be implemented correctly. (However, I'm more used to seeing a single depth variable passed to the recursive function that is subtracted each ply - and returns the evaluated score when it equals 0). But it is hard to diagnose your problem as an outsider due to the large dependency on other code.

*Rather than fishing for you, I feel it would be better to teach you how to fish.* I would suggest spending some time to build a routine that outputs the tree structure and cumulative score visually somehow. It seems as though you already have the building blocks of such a thing, too. It might be time consuming to do this initially, but in the long run will help greatly with debugging - and believe me, with a chess engine, trawling through this tree will be an unfortunately frequent reality, especially when you implement more obscure moves like en-passant - these can cause all sorts of troubles within the tree (I've been there).

Try to output something like this:

```
<move-white ---->
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <best black score>
<move-white ---->
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <best black score>
<move-white ---->
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <move-black ----><eval score>
    <best black score>
<best white score>
```

...where `----` denotes the move.

Obviously this is going to be much larger and deeper, but at least you can see what is happening in a more human friendly way. Hopefully it will help you with other issues in the long run, too. Setting up a good debugging system with a chess engine is vital, as you will probably find.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. I used this method to display me the current board situations of the deepest ply with some scores of my evaluate-function and recognized that there was a little bug. Can't figure out why it worked for one player without the minus-sign, but now the maximization seems to work for both players.

Comment: No worries, glad this helped. Sometimes the most subtle bugs can cause seemingly unrelated problems, especially in something like a chess engine!